# Multiple network interfaces issue

Tags: networking, network-interface, modem, mobile

I've two 3G USB modems (or one USB modem and any other network interface - `eth` or `wlan`).

I connect both interfaces by creating IP rules and adding routes for each one as follows:

```
sb="ip/subnet"
ifn="network interface (ppp0, eth0..etc)"
ipo="interface ip"

ip route add "$sb" dev "$ifn" src "$ipo" table "$tbl"
ip route add "$sb" dev "$ifn" src "$ipo"
ip route add default via "$gw" table "$tbl" 
ip rule add from "$ipo" table "$tbl"
ip rule add to "$ipo" table "$tbl"
```

Both interfaces get connected and each one connected with its full speed independently. The issue starts when I try to download using both interfaces simultaneously:

1. Open a terminal and start a download on the first interface:

   ```
    curl --interface ppp0 "$URL" -o /dev/null
   ```
2. Open another terminal and start a download on the second interface:

   ```
    curl --interface ppp1 "$URL" -o /dev/null
   ```

The issue is both interfaces get slower when both commands run together, the first interface starts with 1.5MBps speed, when the next command starts, the first interface starts dropping in speed. The same happens the other way around, when the second interface starts first, speed drops when the first interface starts.

It's like auto load balancing occurs. I tried with kernel parameters `rp_filter` and `arp_filter`.

To be clear, I don't need load balancing, just need each interface run independently for simultaneous connections.

Thanks!

#### UPDATE

Even with each interface on a different network namespace, they affect each other's speed when run simultaneously.

Comment: have u checked that traffic goes trough interfaces u specify? by tcpdump or wireshark

Comment: @MolbOrg Yes, correct traffic flow

Comment: Are they connected directly to your computer? If so, are you sure they are both connected via independent USB 2.0 channels, and are they actually running at USB 2.0 speeds?

Comment: @JesseKeilson Tried with both on USB 2.0 and USB 3.0, and with each on different on different port (USB 2.0 and 3.0) and using `usbmon` noticed they're not getting more than 7MBps speed in total, while each independently can reach 5MBps in which total should be 10MBps.

Do you think it can be some USB drivers bottleneck? I guess it is, since `usbmon` is monitoring raw USB packets before in networking operations, correct me if it's wrong.

Comment: Could please post more details how you've checked the traffic flow? Is the incoming traffic really routed correctly? Are both ppp connections using different modems? Are both connections using different public IPs? `curl --interface ppp0 https://ifconfig.co`

Comment: @rudimeier Show different external IP addresses, traffic flow showed on tcpdump, packets are routed from/to the ip/interface

Comment: Are both of your cards operated by same ISP (or mobile operator)?

Comment: @Kalavan No, different operators

Comment: @Marware We need reproducible proofs of everything you say, from the sum of the bandwidths being capped to proofs that each interfaces are indeed used independently, including proofs that you are using two independent USB channels which bandwidths are not maxed out. Otherwise we can waste hours figuring out that the summed cap is actually a slight (say 5%) loss of speed which could be caused by interferences between the two dongles or we could figure out that actually everything goes in one interface only, etc. So help us help you.